# How to re-rotate AWS RDS certificates for golang 1.15 compatibility

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, ssl, amazon-rds

I am attempting to resolve the issue described here:
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/39568
and here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL-certificate-rotation.html, where AWS requires customers to re-rotate RDS certificates (rds-ca-2019) to make them compatible with golang 1.15

> If you are using a Go version 1.15 application with a DB instance that was created or updated to the rds-ca-2019 certificate prior to July 28, 2020, you must update the certificate again. Run the modify-db-instance command shown in the AWS CLI section using rds-ca-2019 as the CA certificate identifier. In this case, it isn't possible to update the certificate using the AWS Management Console. If you created your DB instance or updated its certificate after July 28, 2020, no action is required. For more information, see Go GitHub issue #39568.

To be clear, my RDS servers are already using `rds-ca-2019`, but I rotated them before July 28, 2020. When I check the certs using `openssl s_client -starttls mysql [hostname]`, I see a cert without a SAN.

I am issuing this command at the cli, but nothing happens, no pending maintenance is created, the server is not restarted, and the cert continues to be the old one without the SAN.

`aws rds modify-db-instance --db-instance-identifier [db-ident] --ca-certificate-identifier rds-ca-2019 --apply-immediately --certificate-rotation-restart`

I have tried all the permutations with and without the `--apply-immediately` and `--certificate-rotation-restart` flags.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: My AWS cli version is: `aws-cli/2.1.30 Python/3.9.2 Darwin/20.3.0 source/x86_64 prompt/off`

Comment: did you already reach out to AWS support? they are normally pretty good with these kind of issues.

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.DBInstance.Modifying.html) clearly state --apply-immediately will reboot the instance, and --ca-certificate-identifier requires an outage, it's interesting that is not happening.  When you describe the instance via the CLI does it tell you it's using the correct certificate?  

I know that openssl says its off, but I'm wondering if there is a mismatch between what AWS says it is, and what's actually running on the box, and if a reboot would fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

`aws rds modify-db-instance --db-instance-identifier [db-ident] --ca-certificate-identifier rds-ca-2019 --apply-immediately`

If you sit in the RDS console for a minute, the reboot begins ~10 seconds after issuing the command.

When the instance comes back up, it is using a new cert with a SAN, which can be verified with:

`openssl s_client -starttls mysql [db-hostname] < /dev/null 2> /dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -text | grep "Subject Alternative Name"`

I can't explain why it wasn't working for me at the time I posted the question, but I'm perfectly willing to say that it was more likely my fault than AWS. ;)